# When I switch to Cycles from Eevee, the details in my texture are lost

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials, eevee-render-engine, bump

[Link to the blender file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zhFLMs9PVroGHEOUUWc4oL_hJGSHJz22/view?usp=sharing)[[image: material settings1mat2]I'm new to blender.

I did all of the 3d model and materials with Eevee, and when I change it to cycles, I have a problem. In the rendered image, it looks like the bump isn't showing in the render.

When I do the render using Eevee, the bump/detail from the materials looks great, but when I change it to cycles for a better rendering, there´s no bump/detail in the shoe's strip material. Check the comparison in the shoe strips:

[image: I did very similar stuff in most of the materials]

Thanks in advance! [image: 4]

Comment: Hello and welcome. Could you kindly attach a screenshot of your materials or provide your .blend file so we can know the problem?

Comment: Sure thing, I´ve just added a screenshot of one of the materials, I did practically the same process for all of the materials. Thanks!

Comment: Check my edits, it works! (By the way, the top part is not important, just look at my part about changing the bump settings :)

Answer (score 1):

In cycles, you have probably set the settings of the material to *Displacement Only*. Change it to *Bump Only* or *Displacement and Bump* to view it properly in cycles.[image]

**EDIT:** @BCussi the bump appears at my end: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y7581.jpg You just have to zoom in a little, the denoising blurs it out at such a distance. Your image texture is not on my computer, so I can't see the colouring properly, but yeah, it's okay. Try giving it a render and also increase the strength of your displacement if you want, and instead of a distance of 0.005 on the bump nodes, try 0.01 or 0.05. And it also looks like you have plugged the bump node into the height of the other bump node and the wave texture into the strength of that bump node, connect THE NORMAL OF THE Bump Node to the normal input of the next bump node, and the wave texture into the height, not the strength like this: [image]  In Eevee, it appears okay because Eevee automatically tries to guess what it will look like. Cycles however, is more realistic, that is why it uses everything according to real life values.

Comment: Thanks, I  checked and it has in bump only, I am changing it to bump and displacement to check if anything changes but the render looks the same as before. But thanks anyways!

Comment: @BCussi can you switch to cycles and show me your material settings?

Comment: Sure, there you go.

Comment: @BCussi Check my edit, solves the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Update your blender. I remembered I had the same problem 6 months ago when using 2.91. I dont know problem with blender version or not, but you can try sometimes there may be glitch

Comment: I´ve added a link to my file! Please leet me know if you kind the error. Thanks!